# Provably total functions?

Tags: provability

I want to know what does it mean when we say for example 
$$f(x)=2^x$$ is provably total in Peano arithmetic? Also what's the diffrence between provably total and provably recursive?

Comment: You can take a look at the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177535/learning-how-to-prove-that-a-function-cant-proved-total